# Kubernetes Cert-Manager fails issuing certificate with DNS01 webhook

Tags: cluster

I want to learn about cluster computing and I so happens to have 3 x Raspberry Pi laying around.

I also want to learn about Kubernetes, so an excellent way to do this is by installing `K3S` because it is a lightweight certified Kubernetes installation that can run on a Raspberry Pi.

- I have done the [Quick Start guide](https://docs.k3s.io/quick-start) to setup the nodes.
- I have also done the [Installation guide](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/) to `cert-manager`.

And now I need to create a staging `ClusterIssuer`, so I can get certificates from Lets Encrypt.

Since I do not have a public ip for my internet connection, then I have to resort to using the `dns01` webhook in order to issues certificates for my applications running in my cluster server.

I am using [Simply.com](https://www.simply.com/) as my DNS provider and therefore I need to use the [simply-dns-webhook](https://github.com/RunnerM/simply-dns-webhook/tree/master/deploy) in order to issue certificates.

I am using the Issue/ClusterIssue examples almost verbatim with only a few changes to variable names.

I have stored my version in the file `letsencrypt-staging.yaml` with the following content (slightly anonymized):

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    # You must replace this email address with your own.
    # Let's Encrypt will use this to contact you about expiring
    # certificates, and issues related to your account.
    email: mail@example.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # Secret resource that will be used to store the account's private key.
      name: letsencrypt-staging-private-key
    # Add a single challenge solver, HTTP01 using nginx
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        webhook:
          groupName: com.github.runnerm.cert-manager-simply-webhook
          solverName: simply-dns-solver
          config:
            secretName: simply-credentials
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'example.com'
```

And my request for a certificate is stored in the file: `app-certificate.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: app-example-com
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: app-example-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: app.example.com
  dnsNames:
  - app.example.com
```

However after I run the commands:

```
kubectl apply -f letsencrypt-staging.yaml
kubectl apply -f app-certificate.yaml
```

I get the following error from `kubectl describe Challanges app-example-com-X-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX`:

```
Status:
  Presented:   false
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      simply-dns-solver.com.github.runnerm.cert-manager-simply-webhook is forbidden: 
User "system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager" cannot create resource 
"simply-dns-solver" in API group "com.github.runnerm.cert-manager-simply-webhook" 
at the cluster scope
```

Is there anybody who knows what that is about and how to solve it?